# True Last Row and Last Column containing data on a Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Sheet that gets self-refreshing data from an external source. This Sheet which may not have the same lastRow or lastColumn. I need to find a quickest way to determine what is the true lastRow and true lastColumn of the sheet that contains data. I need to exclude cells containing formulas or data validations. Also, as the data refreshes, the rows count and columns count change everytime and therefore sometimes the `getLastRow()` and `getLastColumn()` donot work correctly but include blanks.

I have seen some code which requires you to input a particular column or row number inorder to identify its last data row or data column. I want to know if there is a way to exclude such an input.

```
  function DoIt(){

    var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var Rng = sht.getDataRange().getValues();

    Rng.forEach(function (row,index) {
        if (row[0] == "") {                   // row[0] is the same as Column A. row[1] = B
            Rng.length = index;
        }
    });
    var newRange = sht.getRange(Rng.length,1);
    Logger.log(newRange.getA1Notation());
}
```

For example, in the below image, the `lastRow` should be `row 11` as there is a value in `cell D11` and `lastColumn` should be `column F` as there is value in `cell F3`. So [row: 11, col: 6] should be the immediate answer.

[image: data range]

Is there an efficient and quicker way to find the true lastrow and lastcolumn of a sheet?

Comment: If you were to get the lastRow() and the lastColumn() for that sheet then row 11 and column 6 is what you would get.  So what's the problem?

Comment: @Cooper as new data gets pulled from an external source to the sheet, the earlier rows may get removed which results in the getLastRow() or getLastColumn() to report the wrong row number or column number. Or there may be blanks or data validations left behind. Its difficult to pinpoint why it doesnt work sometimes, but yes, i have encountered this situation with refreshing data. It seems sort of an earlier UsedRange (like in Excel) still persists in the Sheet. So incorrect lastrow or lastcolumn gets reported.

Comment: If the data is changing and you rerun sheet.getLastRow() does it return the correct result or is it because you not executing the function again after the change.

Comment: data changes every hour. There is a time-based trigger which runs 15 mins after data changes. The result is getLastRow gives the previous row value or max row value instead of the new lastrow value.

Comment: Well I must admit that I never use cell functions so I have never seen that behavior.  Where does the  data come from?

Comment: its from an internal resource of my company.

Comment: have you tried using [`flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) before checking with `getLastRow()`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried Spreadsheet App.flush() also at the end.

Comment: @sifar - at the end? It looks like you get a race condition here: the changes are still pending when you try to ask the spreadsheet for the current last row. Please update your question to include clarifications from comments for ease of reference.

Comment: I would need an [mcve] to tackle this problem.  Just the minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made these one-line functions for finding the true lastColumn or true lastRow on a sheet which does not take into account specifying any particular row or column and gives me the correct result.

```
function FindLastRow(sht) {
  return sht.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getLastRow();
};

function FindLastColumn(sht) {
  return sht.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getLastColumn();
};
    
function test(){
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActivesheet();
  lr = FindLastRow(sht);
  lc = FindLastColumn(sht);
}
```

Not sure of speeds! If someone can test and confirm, it would be worth the try!

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that the problem occurs because your aren't comparing the last row / column at the same point in time.

As you are using `var Rng = sht.getDataRange().getValues();`
the last row is `Rng.length` and the last column is `Rng[0].length`. They should be the same as `sht.getLastRow()` and `sht.getLastColumn()`.

If you are applying changes to a spreadsheet you should wait for the spreadsheet update process finish and the updates spread across Google data centers before reading again the last row / column.

You might consider to add a timestamp somewhere (maybe a property, maybe a cell) for the last change made by your time-driven trigger to be sure which spreadsheet "revision" are you reading.

Comment: Unfortunately its not the case I see here. I removed the trigger and am running it manually. Same issue.

Comment: to be sure just use SpreadSheetApp.flush() to be sure that the spreadsheet is updated with all current changes.